# Cognito Sync Javascript Offline access

Tags: amazon-cognito

Scenario
1) App launched first time, cognito crdentails and CognitoSync are set, Datasets created and values are populated. App is closed
2)  Device is offline
3) App is launched, Can we access CognitoSync and ftech the datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript SDK for Cognito does allow offline access to datasets. Cognito uses local storage to save the datasets for just this reason.

Comment: Jeff What i am seeing in the javascript sdk always i have to Instantiate the aws credentials for which internet connection is must correct me if i am wrong, Please see my code below,  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    });
    var syncClient = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();

    syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("myDataset", function(err, dataset) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err)+"dsfdgvdfgedgf"+JSON.stringify(dataset));
      //  ds = dataset; //
    });

Comment: Some sample code is in the github repo https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js and a blog post https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx39MLGTYNTD5BK/Push-synchronization-JavaScript-sync-and-eu-west-1-for-Amazon-Cognito

Comment: Yes i followed your blog, i couldn't understand with out an internet connection how that code will work, especially aws credentials, what i am trying to do is, when internet is not there then retrieve the values stored in the localstorage.( I am just starting on this what i am missing here),

Comment: That code doesn't necessarily contact AWS, it's just initializing the clients. The credentials provider won't make a network call unless something asks it to - the constructor does not. The sync client is the same way, and openOrCreateDataset is what gets it from the local storage. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks that has cleared, i have tried it and started getting results, Is there any API available for CognitoSyncmanager. which gives us more insights.

Comment: The only publicly available samples are linked above, but the Cognito sync API reference is available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html